# IPTables 1:1 NAT on a single port

Tags: linux, networking, firewall, iptables, nat

I am trying to figure out how to add a 1:1 NAT with IPTables but only on a single port, I know how to forward all traffic, but can't seem to find anything on a single port such as

```
192.168.1.1:21 -> 172.16.1.1:21   
192.168.1.2:21 -> 172.16.1.2:21   
192.168.1.3:21 -> 172.16.1.3:21   
192.168.1.4:21 -> 172.16.1.4:21
```

I cant do this by say allowing only one port because there are other applications also doing traffic redirections on other ports.

All I have so far is something like this, but it doesn't specify the IP it originally landed on as a parameter.

```
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1   
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport port -j DNAT --to-destination ip:port   
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the -d flag to specify original destination.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d <external-ip> -p tcp --dport port -j DNAT --to-destination <internal-ip>:port
```